# SQL Query to SELECT strings which are either words

Tags: sql

I am working on the following query:Find the country where the capital is the country plus "City". Hopefully, you can infer what I mean:

The following query will solve such:

```
SELECT world.name
  FROM world
WHERE world.capital LIKE CONCAT(world.name, " City")
```

Now, say that I also wanted to match for another word, Town. We could do something like this:

```
SELECT world.name
  FROM world
WHERE world.capital LIKE CONCAT(world.name, " City") OR world.capital LIKE CONCAT(world.name, " Town")
```

Can I condense the above statement to only one LIKE clause? Say something like this?

```
SELECT world.name
 FROM world
WHERE world.capital LIKE CONCAT(world.name, " [City,Town]")
```

I just want a more terse SQL statement

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: PostgresSQL, but I'd love to hear any other solutions

Answer (score 1):

Doing what you want requires regular expressions, whose support depends on the database.  You cannot easily do this with `LIKE`.

Because "city" and "town" have the same number of letters and most databases support `right()`, you could do:

```
where world.capital like concat(world.name, ' ____') and
      right(world.capital, 4) in ('City', 'Town')
```

I think, however, that the method with two `like`s or using regular expressions is cleaner.

Comment: Hmm, that looks pretty nasty. Is there any solution here?

Comment: @zero . . . Your original approach is fine.